# I'd like to discuss about re-opening my question, as I do not find it to be a duplicate

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

Earlier this morning, I posted a question that I genuinely felt was not a duplicate in any way, shape, or form. However, it was downvoted and closed by a single user who felt that it was, and I wanted to discuss it and why I feel it should be re-opened.

[This is the question I posted.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75522749/how-to-update-refresh-window-with-new-content-after-clicking-on-an-option-and-p)

The reason given for it being closed and considered a duplicate is because the user felt it was asked before, apparently. [This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990137/pygame-mouse-clicking-detection) they provided as a reasoning. I believe they didn't actually bother to read my question, and just assumed I was wanting to know how to get the program to recognize I clicked on something. No. My question is completely different to that one, which was asked over ten years ago. The question they provided even begins with, "*I was wondering how to write code that would **detect the mouse clicking on a sprite**.*" I was not asking for that kind of help at all. I was asking how to refresh a window to show new content and remove all traces of previously given options. I mean, to me, those're two different things. Also, the answers provided in the 10-year-old question did not address the problem of what I was needing help with.

Comment: I mean... at first glance, as someone with *no* python experience, they look fairly similar, ignoring that the answers there are using collision to detect if the mouse is in a given range vs your direct approach. I'd expect the method of detecting a hit wouldn't be relevant to the logic that fixes the problem?

Comment: @KevinB I mean, to me, detecting mouse detection and refreshing a window with new content are two different things. I already have it to where it'll detect I'm clicking on something and create a new "page". I'm looking for how to either "remove" those previous options so they can't be accessed anymore or make a new, blank slate.

Comment: My understanding of your problem is, you have defined a clickable area, and after "changing views" that clickable area is still a clickable area, which is different enough from the duplicate IMO given it's generally just about detecting clicks. I don't think any of the answers address your problem, but again, not an SME

Comment: *"I believe they didn't actually bother to read my question"* ... speaking of "didn't actually bother to read", the banner says "This question already has answers here", so have you read the answers on the linked question? What the question itself says or contains is not important. When the linked answers don't answer your question, then there is something to do.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, exactly! I'm glad to see that my question was, indeed, not a duplicate.

Comment: @Tom The answers provided in the 10-year-old question were not relevant for what I was needing help on.

Comment: Then this is the argumentation you should use. That the question is different is not important.

Comment: @Tom I have since updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: Concerning your comment to the question - "Think logically: why would a Python beginner think that "refreshing window content" is the exact same as "mouse clicking detection" and correlate the two? They wouldn't." - This is a bad "anti-duplicate" reasoning because the exact purpose of a duplicate is to tell for *everyone* (including beginners) that two problems are *effectively* the same. (For clearness: I don't tell whether your question is duplicate or not. I just tell that your specific *reasoning* is bad).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't see how it's bad reasoning because a beginner is not going to necessarily correlate mouse click detection with window data refreshing. They're simply not the same thing, they are two different things. I'm saying to see it from a beginner's point of view, not an experience person's point of view.

Comment: No one is saying that we aren't sorting it from a beginning point of view, but that (that you arr asking about refrahinging rather than mouse detection) doesn't make the 2 questions not duplicates (I also am not an SME, so can't judge myself).

Comment: You may want to remove "click" from the title "How to update/refresh window with new content **after clicking on an option**, and **prevent previous options from being clickable**" - so far most of the title focus on clicks rather than anything else... Please remember that we don't specifically care about you personally getting an answer - we care for you to ask a question that is useful for future visitors and those future visitors matching their problem with an answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I honestly thought having "selecting" instead of "clicking" would've been the wrong terminology for it. I have now updated my question to reflect "selecting" instead.

Comment: FWIW, it would immensely help if you would edit your question to be more focused on the actual issue. Right now it is a huge wall of text and code. That necessarily invites people to guess what the fundamental problem is, and may thus lead to answers or moderation missing your intended problem.

Comment: @ChiliBeef surprisingly this question does not mention anything about clicks - "...asking how to refresh a window to show new content and remove all traces of previously given options" - I don't know why you now think the title must include word "click" at all... but that was just a suggestion in case you plan to make the SO question looking less duplicate of click-related one.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Because I am still new to all of this, I did not know what the correct vernacular should be. I mean, technically, I _am_ clicking on the text (which is really a `rect`), so I thought that's what I should've called it. What would you call it? I'm being honest, what would you suggest so that I know for next time?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi My apologies, I was torn between being not-too-vague or being overly specific; the suggestion window to the right when creating a new question said to be sure to include any necessary information. I wanted to make sure I didn't leave anything pertinent out. I'll go about rewording my question to something less dense.

Comment: The best thing you can do is to copy the ["source"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75522749/revisions) of your latest revision and draft elsewhere. Then you would be ready to submit the edit when the queue lets you. Hopefully they fix it soon.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm sorry, but no. That is not relevant to what my original discussion was about.

Answer (score 11):

I've more or less come to the conclusion that it *is still a duplicate.

The root of your issue here is enabling/disabling the detection of clicks within a given area after an action has been taken. Yes, the target doesn't *directly* ask for that, but the most upvoted answer addresses this scenario in two different ways, one that pretty closely matches your scenario.

*The unfortunate (fortunate?) part here is that even though I think they are duplicates due to the answer addressing your problem, the answer doesn't really focus on that side of the problem in a way such that it would point out the flaws in your own logic. For that reason... I wouldn't be against it not being closed as a duplicate and having an answer focusing on that logic problem specifically.

But, again, I'm not an SME and would prefer people who actually know Python take action in this case.