# Full edit queue blocking edits on own post

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits

In the question [I'd like to discuss about re-opening my question, as I do not find it to be a duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423308/6083675), OP revealed something significant: the edit queue was full and that was preventing them from editing their own question. You don't need any privileges to edit your own posts so the fact that the edit queue is full shouldn't matter. (Fortunately, it looks like they are able to make edits when the queue isn't full.) Here is a screenshot from the comments on that post:

[image: too many pending edits]

I suspect this is related to the changes here: [Allow edits which have already started even when queue is full](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398145/6083675)

Apparently this affects any use of the full page editor, which means anyone can reproduce the issue. I was able to reproduce it myself by opening an [edit in a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42440851/edit). (Thanks, Ivar for this info.) This also probably means that low-rep (specifically 100–1999 rep) users can't always edit Community Wiki posts.

Comment: [I'm able to reproduce this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6TXM.png) with full editing privilege as well by opening the edit link in a new tab. (As long as the suggested edit queue is full).

Comment: Meta.SE report: [Users without full editing privileges are unable to edit their own posts or community wiki posts when the suggested edit queue is full](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386906/users-without-full-editing-privileges-are-unable-to-edit-their-own-posts-or-comm)

Comment: Thank you for the report - we're shipping a fix soon.  Our goal was to provide a continuity of experience for people beginning an edit when the queue wasn't full, to reserve them a slot while on the edit page in case the edit queue filled up in the meantime.

Comment: I'll just add here that I hate the fixed size edit queue with a passion. Having my edits linger in my browser while I wait for a slot is a very bad user experience.

Comment: @code11: Having suggested edits come in faster than they're processed would also be a bad experience, because then the suggested edit queue would just continue to grow in size forever, and a lot of suggested edits would eventually just start aging out (I believe). It's a delicate balancing act. If folks are annoyed by the limit on the total number of pending suggested edits, then the community needs to handle the existing review tasks in that queue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should be fixed now.  We've rolled back changes intended to [allow edits which have already started even when queue is full](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398145/1366033), which reserved a slot for people who began an edit when the review queue was under capacity until they finished their edit. Sorry for the disruption

Comment: I struggle to understand why the change had such an effect. When I, as OP, attempt to edit my own post, why would Stack Overflow's codebase make **any consideration whatsoever** of the status of the edit queue?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It *shouldn't* have had any impact, that's why it was a bug.  When users land on the edit page, we validate that they have the permission to be there for a whole host of reasons. And while modifying that validation logic, introduced the error.